# Livescribe Developer : File IO : Saving Variables to Smartpen

Tags: file-io, java-me, local-storage, livescribe

I am a stubborn 3rd party developer for the old Livescribe smartpen platform.  I have developed a number of paper products and minor penlets for the Echo Smartpen.

Because there is no formal, official support, I am reaching out to any other developers out there that can answer a very basic question about file management.

The Echo smartpen utilizes the J2ME environment.  I want to be able to save and update integer and string variables to the pen's internal memory/storage system.  I want the penlet to be able to create the file if it does not already exist, and search through the file if it exists for the variable name and either read or write as appropriate.

I'm still learning File IO in general and have looked through various tutorials on the subject.  However, I have come to understand that the Echo Smartpen uses a slightly different mechanism to save files and information.  Unfortunately, the wayback machine archive shows the forum postings in the old Livescribe developer forums, but the individual topic threads were never picked up by their systems... so the solution I am looking for seems to have been lost.

If there are any old Livescribe developers that frequent this forum, any information that you might be able to provide me on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Ideally, a simple example with two functions, saveGame and loadGame, where we save integer variables questNumber, health, and gold and string variable questName or load the same variables, would be ideal.

Joseph.